# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_value'` on df = pd.concat(dfs)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, airflow

I am getting error on pd.concat(df) the error is given below

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 192, in execute return_value = self.execute_callable() ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 209, in execute_callable return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/scripts/run_daily_marketplace.py", line 38, in main df_data = etl.get_marketplace_data(query_params) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/helpers/etl.py", line 834, in get_marketplace_data df = pd.concat(dfs) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 393, in concat return op.get_result() ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 680, in get_result new_data = concatenate_managers( ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/concat.py", line 189, in concatenate_managers values = _concatenate_join_units(join_units, copy=copy) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/concat.py", line 466, in _concatenate_join_units to_concat = [ ^ File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/concat.py", line 467, in <listcomp> ju.get_reindexed_values(empty_dtype=empty_dtype, upcasted_na=upcasted_na) File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/concat.py", line 452, in get_reindexed_values return make_na_array(empty_dtype, self.block.shape, fill_value) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 2294, in make_na_array i8values = np.full(shape, fill_value._value) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_value'
```

My old versions were the below ( I never faced this issue on these versions)
Airflow version = 2.2.2
Pandas = 1.3.5

Current version (With error)
Airflow version = 2.7.2
Pandas = 2.1.1

can someone help, Thanks!

```
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

I was expecting it to work like before

Comment: Pls share the value of `dfs`

Comment: Hi , I saw a comment before which suggested to replace NaT values with None, I tried that and it worked because I had NaT values in my DFs and new versions of pandas does not work with them

dfs = [df.replace({None: pd.NaT}) for df in dfs]